# Is $(p)$, $p$ prime, ideal prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ideals

Is correct the following? I want verify if $(p)$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ ($p$ prime) I have this:    $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(p)\simeq (\mathbb{Z}[x]/(p))[y]\simeq (\mathbb{Z}_{p}[x])[y]$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is a field then $(\mathbb{Z}_{p}[x])$ is a Euclidean domain. From here I don't know what more information to get

Comment: Essentially, you are done: you have a polynomial ring over a domain, which is a domain.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774679/showing-that-a-ideal-in-mathbbzx-y-is-prime).

Comment: Yes, you have shown that the quotient is an integral domain, which happens if and only if the quotiented ideal is prime.

Comment: oh I see. By the same reason (p,x) is prime? I have this: $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(p,x)\simeq (\mathbb{Z}[x]/(p,x))[y]\simeq (\mathbb{Z}_{p}[x]/(x))[y]\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{p}[y]$, so is prime right?

Answer (score 1):

As you have shown that $$\frac{\Bbb Z[x,y]}{(p)} \cong (\Bbb Z_p[x])[y]$$

Now $\Bbb Z_p \text{ is a field } \implies \Bbb Z_p[x] \text{ is a PID } \implies (\Bbb Z_p[x])[y] \text{ is an Integral Domain} \implies (p) \in \operatorname{Spec(\Bbb Z[x,y])}$